# Dynamically assign component to routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to have dynamic routes? For example; we get the request `mywebsite.com/foo-bar` and the router checks if the component `FooBar` exists and assigns that component or if it doesn't exist it assigns a default component `BasePage`.

For example:

```
import * as pages from '../components/pages'

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/:slug',
      component: (!_.isNull(pages[slug]) ? pages[slug] : BasePage,
      props: true
    },
  ]
  ...
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, you should add one more component (like HOC) and decide what to show in it. Or you can check it in router hooks (beforeEach) and make redirect to BasePage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this, but I think something like this should work.

```
import * as pages from '../components/pages'

const routes = pages.map(page => {
    return {
        path: `/${page.name}`,
        name: page.name,
        component: page
    }
})

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    },
    ...routes,
    {
        path: '*',
        name: 'Default',
        component: DefaultComponent
    }
  ]
});
```